# Implementation of type(name, bases, dict_)

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand how [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) works, specifically the three-argument form. How would this look?

Here's my shot, but this is a TypeError.

```
def type_(name, bases, dict_):
    base = next(base for base in bases if hasattr(base, '__new__'))
    return super(type(base)).__new__(type(base))

type('A', (int, object,), {}) # __main__.A
type_('A', (int, object,), {})

TypeError: super.__new__(type): type is not a subtype of super
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `super` here?

Comment: `type` is a class, like `list`, or `str`. It creates class-objects. It is a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes type is a class. Is it possible to show what `type()` does, using a function or a class?

Comment: [There is a very nice explanation on metaclasses and type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/5741172), Have a look.